# row record not updating in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i need help on my code below. Im using codeigniter as my framework for this development

View

```
<table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Username</th>
                            <th>Email Address</th>
                            <th>Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                        <?php foreach($query as $row){?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php print $row->id; ?></td>
                            <td><?php print $row->username; ?></td>
                            <td><?php print $row->email; ?></td>
                            <td><?=anchor('userslist/get_Admin/'.$row->id, 'Edit');?>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<?=anchor('userslist/deleteAdmin/'.$row->id, 'Delete');?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php }?>
                    </table>
```

Controller

```
        function get_Admin($id)
    {
        $data['query']=$this->usermodel->get_Admin($id);
        $this->load->view('admin/users/edit-user-template',$data);
    }
```

View (update forms)

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Update an Admin Account</th>
    </tr>
     <?php echo form_open('userslist/update_admin'); ?>
    <tr>
        <td>Username</td>
        <td>
        <?php
            $data = array('name'=>'username', 'id'=>'username', 'class'=>'signup-txtbox', 'value'=>$query['username']);
            echo form_input($data);
        ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td>
        <?php
            $data = array('name'=>'email', 'id'=>'email', 'class'=>'signup-txtbox', 'value'=>$query['email']);
            echo form_input($data);
        ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Password</td>
        <td>
        <?php
            $data = array('name'=>'password', 'id'=>'password', 'class'=>'signup-txtbox', 'value'=>'');
            echo form_input($data);
        ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Confirm Password</td>
        <td>
        <?php
            $data = array('name'=>'password2', 'id'=>'password2', 'class'=>'signup-txtbox', 'value'=>'');
            echo form_input($data);
        ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
        <?php
            $data = array('name'=>'submit', 'id'=>'submit', 'class'=>'signup-btn', 'value'=>'Update Acccount');
            echo form_submit($data);
        ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><?php echo validation_errors('<p class="error">'); ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

controller

```
        function update_admin()
        {
            $this->usermodel->update_admin();
            redirect('userslist');
```

}

Model

```
        function update_admin()
    {
        $update_admin_data = array(
                'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'password ' => md5($this->input->post('password '))
            );
            $this->db->where('id',$id);
            $update = $this->db->update('users', $update_admin_data);
            return $update;
    }
```

the whole code doesn't update the selected record it just happens that it just redirects to the page without the update. what could be the possible solution for this?

thanks!

Comment: You cant just post a whole mess of code and ask somebody to help. Can you provide us with some specific info?

Comment: In your model, where is $id coming from in $this->db->where('id',$id)??

Comment: it's coming from my view...it is  being triggered by a hyperlink


<td><?=anchor('userslist/get_Admin/'.$row->id, 'Edit');?>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<?=anchor('userslist/deleteAdmin/'.$row->id, 'Delete');?></td>

Comment: ok so its part of the URL? Where do you set the value of the PHP variable $id though (maybe im just skimming over it...)

Comment: and we need more info, like what happens when you try and do something. do you get an error?

Comment: i was able to load the specific record that i selected but then problem is when i try to update it with different values the record doesn't reflect that update. it just redirects to the another page with no error. i tried to check the logs but no error was triggered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `$id` attribute. Update the form submit in your second view:

```
<?php echo form_open('userslist/update_admin/'.$query['id']); ?>
```

Fix your second controller:

```
function update_admin($id)
        {
            $this->usermodel->update_admin($id);
            redirect('userslist');
}
```

Finally, fix your `update_admin` model function to start like this:

```
 function update_admin($id)
    {
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is where your problem is

```
$this->db->where('id',$id);
```

the variable `$id` is not defined within your model function, therefor when you try and do the `$this->db->where('id',$id);` $id is not a variable, hence doesnt find anything...hence not updating.

if `$id` is part of the uri do something like:

```
$id = $this->uri->segment(3) //or whatever the segment is going to be
```

Comment: yep, i just recently added the URI function to get the specific ID and the parameter to get the update done but nothing changes

Comment: function update_admin()
  {
   $update_admin_data = array(
     'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
     'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
     'password ' => md5($this->input->post('password '))
    );
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3, 0);
    $this->db->where('id',$id);
    $update = $this->db->update('users', $update_admin_data);
    return $update;
  }

Comment: can you check what $this->uri->segment(3, 0) value is please

Comment: i was able to get the corresponding, id for the record when i used the $id = $this->uri->segment(3);     $this->db->where('id',$id);